# Javascript to get all the paragraph of the body

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get all the paragraph tag from the body and set an attribute to
 them, but i'm unable to do so.

```
getElementByTagName("p")
```

does not works and

```
getElementByTagName("p")[n]
```

selects gives me only the particular tag name

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arrOfPtags = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i = 0;i < arrOfPtags.length; i++){
     arrOfPtags[i].setAttribute("desired_attribute", "value");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the guidance, it worked :)

Comment: @Ankit if the answer helped you in any way, could you please upvote it.

Comment: i don't have enough reputation to do so, sorry about that :(

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried with plural?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/y12s1t6y/)

Comment: its getting me all the tags ,but not allowing me to set their attribute

Comment: it works but i net to set their attribute

Comment: Edit fiddle so it works and edit my answer so we have complete answer.

Comment: thanks for your time, Vinit Sharma's solution helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `document.getElementsByTagName("p");`

```html
<p>
   I
</p>
<p>
   am
</p>
<P>
   an
</P>
<p>
   example
</p>
<script>
   var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
   for (var i = 0;i < elems.length; i++){
      elems[i].style.border = "1px solid red"
   }

</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the help :)